# Angular2 - add HTML attributes and classes dynamically

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

Could you please help me to find an answer of how to dynamically add an attribute && class to the HTML template in Angular 2?

Eg.:

```
<div class="some-class class-8" col-8></div>
```

8 in above example should come from configuration property, but if specific property is not defined, then **col-** and **class-** shouldn't be injected.

Please do not point out that this type of attribute is a bug (this case occurs in Ionic2)

Answer (score 7):

[attr.col-8] is the right syntax, but the condition should return empty string (true, attribute is set) or null (false, attribute is not set).
For example:

```
[attr.col-6]="field.width == 6 ? '' : null"
```

does work fine.
(i am working with ionic 3)

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic classes you can use this :

```
<div [ngClass]="{'some-class': true, 'class-8': true}">...</div>
```

For attribute you can use ::

```
<div [attr.col-8]='true' > </div>
```

Here true/false are `Boolean` values , so you can set `conditions` also , to add class/attribute when some condition satisfied.

If you want to modify col number via @Input()

```
@Input(dynamicVar)dynamicVar:String;
<div {{ dynamicVar !== '' ? 'col-'+dynamicVar : '' }} > </div>
```

Comment: yes, great but what if I want to modify col number via @Input() ? As I've mentioned, parameter / configuration should come dynamically, so it can be col-8, col-4, col-2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

even i put false : [attr.col-12]='false'  the arribute is set to the tag.
I work with angular4/ionic3

Comment: See the answer of cyptus. For the attribute to be removed, the expression has to evaluate to null.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45236859/3764913