# Angular 2 - css attribute selector example in angular 2

Tags: angular

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43306621/10593587. Is there an example for this one. As I am new to Angular I am unable to add `"<div {{ dynamicVar !== '' ? 'col-'+dynamicVar : '' }} > </div>"` in the component template

Comment: Please expand your question to contain all the relevant information as opposed to referencing another SO question. And add enough of your code attempt so it can been seen what you have tried.

Comment: As per the question you linked, you're missing: `[ngClass]=`